# How to resolve unmarshalling exception?

Tags: jaxb, xsd

I am trying to learn JAXB. I created sample as below, but during unmarshalling i am getting exception. My files are below. Can you help me to resolve?

**AddRequest.java:**

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "AddRequest", namespace = "http://www.example.org/AddRequest", propOrder = {
    "first",
    "sec",
    "any"
})
public class AddRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "First")
    protected int first;
    @XmlElement(name = "Sec")
    protected int sec;
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    protected List<Object> any;


}
```

**ObjectFactory.java**

```
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _AddRequest_QNAME = new QName("http://www.example.org/AddRequest", "AddRequest");

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }


    public AddRequest createAddRequest() {
        return new AddRequest();
    }


    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.example.org/AddRequest", name = "AddRequest")
    public JAXBElement<AddRequest> createAddRequest(AddRequest value) {
        return new JAXBElement<AddRequest>(_AddRequest_QNAME, AddRequest.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

**package-info.java**

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://www.example.org/AddRequest", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package org.example.addrequest;
```

**Main.java**

```
try {

            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\nbkyooh\\IBM\\rationalsdp\\workspace\\Sample\\resource\\AddRequest.xml");
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(org.example.addrequest.AddRequest.class);

            Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
             jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**AddRequest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:AddRequest xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/AddRequest" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/AddRequest AddRequest.xsd ">
  <tns:First>0</tns:First>
  <tns:Sec>0</tns:Sec>
</tns:AddRequest>
```

I am getting exception as below, what i have done wrong. I used all the generated files.

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: Unexpected element "{http://www.example.org/AddRequest}AddRequest". Expected elements are "".
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.msg.JAXBMessageProvider.throwUnmarshalExceptionWrapper(JAXBMessageProvider.java:93)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.DeserializationContext.handleSkippedRootElementEvent(DeserializationContext.java:318)
    at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.impl.JAXBDocumentScanner.produceRootElementEvent(JAXBDocumentScanner.java:189)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("your file"));
        AddRequest req = JAXB.unmarshal(inputStream, AddRequest.class);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This is also working. But i couldnt understand. Why my code is not working..?

Comment: @Manoj - This will get you the result unmarshalled, but it won't process the `ObjectFactory` class which can cause different problems based on your model.

Answer (score 1):

In your use case you have define the root element information leveraging the `@XmlElementDecl` annotation on a `ObjectFactory` class annotated with `@XmlRegistry` (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/07/jaxb-and-root-elements.html).  Since the class annotated with `@XmlRegistry` can be called anything and JAXB doesn't do package scanning you need to include your `ObjectFactory` as one of the classes passed in to bootstrap the `JAXBContext`.

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(AddRequest.class, ObjectFactory.class);
```

Since the `ObjectFactory` class references `AddRequest` you could simplify this down to:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
```

Comment: Actually, both are working. How to do that, if i have different schema. If i have another schema which will also has Object factory. How jaxb knows about it.?

Comment: @Manoj - If your JAXB model was generated from an XML schema, then you should create the `JAXBContext` on the generated package name (i.e.  `JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example.foo");`.  This will cause the `JAXBContext` to be processed automatically.  If you are creating the `JAXBContext` on classes you need to include the `ObjectFactory` class as in my answer.

Comment: your answer is really helpful. I had another package generated by different schema. I added them into context. Actually, it gets marshalled.

Now, all my learning is for Apached CXF's Rest service. Actually, cxf itself unmarshall the xml with the generated classses and gives me object. In that case, how do i make cxf know about my other packages?